# StringList recursion method in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have a question regarding a method using linked lists and recursion.
My linked list is called StringList, is basically a linked list with 3 values.
data is the letter.
value is the number of times the letter appears in order.
next is the next node.

I am trying to make a method called equals that basically returns true or false if the 2 StringLists are equal using **RECURSION**.

This is what I tried doing now, but it doesn't seem to work correctly for me, if anyone can help with making this method work correctly, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public boolean equals(StringList str){
    if(str._head == null || _head == null){
        return false;
    }
    CharNode p = _head;
    CharNode b = str._head;
    int value = p.getValue(), valueTwo = str._head.getValue(), index = 0;
    return equals(b,p,value,valueTwo,index);
}

public boolean equals(CharNode b, CharNode p, int value, int valueTwo, int index){
    index++;
    if(p == null || b == null){
        return true;
    }
    if(p.getData() != b.getData()){
        return false;
    }

    if(value == index && p.getNext()!= null) {
        equals(b, p = p.getNext(), value += p.getNext().getValue(), valueTwo, index);
    }
    if(valueTwo == index && b.getNext()!= null){
         equals(b = b.getNext(), p, value, valueTwo = b.getNext().getValue(), index);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: "_doesn't seem to work correctly_" - you will need to be much more specific than "doesn't work". Errors? Exceptions? Wrong output? What is the _exact_ issue?

Comment: Sorry, for example in the 2 strings, "abcde" and 2nd String "a" it returns true, even tho they are not equal. the only thing equal is the first letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step, try to simplify your code to make it easier to debug:
If you have p, b as arguments why also have p.getValue() and b.getValue() as arguments? And what is the difference between value and data?

If your CharNode has the methods getNext() and getData(), you could implement equals like this:

```
public boolean equals(CharNode a, CharNode b) {
  if (a == null && b == null) {
    return true;
  }
  if ((a==null) ||  (b==null)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (a.getData() != b.getData()) {
    return false;
  }
  return equals(a.getNext(), b.getNext());
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your comment, but the difference between data and value is that the data is the letter representation of the String, and value is the number of times the letter appears in order. For example in the String "aab" there are only 2 nodes, 1 which holds Data as "a" and value as 2, and the other node that holds Data as "b" and value as 1. Understand?

Comment: that's a rather unusual StringList, but as long as you make sure there is a unique stringList representation for each string you could simply modify above code to compare data and value in the third if. It gets more tricky if the string aab can be represented both as (1a)(1a)(1b) and (2a)(1b). In that case you probably need to carry around subindexes for both current CharNodes and take them into account when you compare the data and calculate next fields. I would seriously consider renaming **getData** to **getCount** or something similar.

Comment: on a second thought, you could also create wrappers for (1a)(1a) on the fly during equals: if the current a or b node is followed by a node with the same char, you instead call equals on a new node with the combined length - this node does not actually have to be part of the list but it needs to point to the next node. This may not be the fastest implementation as it creates extra garbage and calling new in equals may seem somewhat unusual but it is probably doable in a concise way.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your help, no there cannot be 2 nodes that represent the same letter one after the other, if there is a string "aaaba" it will be represented as NODE1 - data "a",value 3, NODE2 - data "b",value 1, NODE3 - data "a", value 1.